# Circular BoxDecoration shadow gets cut in a box shape on web, not on mobile

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, mobile-development

I'm trying to display a circular image with a shadow, but on Flutter web, the shadow gets cut at the edges, while working fine on mobile.

[image]

Minimum code to reproduce is:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          children: [
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(color: Colors.black, blurRadius: 12.0),
                        ],
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        image: DecorationImage(
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                            image: NetworkImage(
                                'https://images.theconversation.com/files/93616/original/image-20150902-6700-t2axrz.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&q=45&auto=format&w=1000&fit=clip')))),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried adding padding to the container but it didn't help, not sure what else to do.

Comment: Try to use CircleAvatarr() widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick workaround - Add one more container on top and set it as transparent with your fixed size.
    color: Colors.transparent

This makes it draw the entire container therefore not clipping it's child container, so you can add padding to the child and make enough space for the shadows.

```
Container(
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  color: Colors.transparent,
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
    child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(color: Colors.black, blurRadius: 12.0),
        ],
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            image: DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                image: NetworkImage(
                    'https://images.theconversation.com/files/93616/original/image-20150902-6700-t2axrz.jpg')))),
  ),
),
```

Reference: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32215#issuecomment-596143172